# How to add a user to group programatically in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Django project where each user belongs to just one group, Doctor and Nurse but not both.
I showed a form in my front-end to let Admin users add the user profiles, where each user profile is made with First name, Last name, Email, Groups etc.
My challenge is when an admin user assigns a user profile to a group from the front-end that user is not added to the group when I check the Django admin i.e when I click on the on user on the Django admin I can't see the user being assigned to the group.
**The important part of my forms.py is this part**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

groups = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Role', queryset=Group.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

**The full form can be seen here**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django_starter_app.models import User, Post
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Enter Username'}))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Email'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='Firstname', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Firstname'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Lastname', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Lastname'}))
    groups = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Role', queryset=Group.objects.all(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Confirm Password'}))
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'groups', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.groups = self.cleaned_data['groups']
        user.password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        user.password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']

        if commit:
            user.save()
            return user
```

**on my views**

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reg = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if reg.is_valid():
            reg.save()
            role= reg.cleaned_data.get('groups')
            if role== 1:
                doctor_group = Group.objects.get(name='Doctor')
                reg.groups.add(doctor_group)
                return redirect('register_user')
            elif role == 2:
                nurse_group = Group.objects.get(name='Nurse')
                reg.groups.add(nurse_group)
                return redirect('register_user')

    else:
        reg = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'django_starter_app/register.html', {'register':reg})
```

Please I will like to know where I am getting it wrong I suspect where I am making the checks

```
if role == 1:
        doctor_group = Group.objects.get(name='Doctor')
        reg.groups.add(doctor_group)
        return redirect('register_user')
elif role == 2:
        nurse_group = Group.objects.get(name='Nurse')
        reg.groups.add(nurse_group)
        return redirect('register_user')
```

Comment: I have an error after making changes to my code `Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead.`

Answer (score 0):

```
    reg = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if reg.is_valid():
        **user = reg.save()**
        role= reg.cleaned_data.get('groups')
        if role== 1:
            doctor_group = Group.objects.get(name='Doctor')
            **user.groups.add(doctor_group)**
             ModelName.objects.create( user = user,)
            return redirect('register_user')
        elif role == 2:
            nurse_group = Group.objects.get(name='Nurse')
            **user.groups.add(nurse_group)**
            ModelName.objects.create( user = user,)
            return redirect('register_user')
```

Once you have validated the form you need a variable to hold the save form.
After getting the groups you need to use that variable.

I have highlighted the required changes in the code.

Comment: the code did not work I have this error `Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead.`

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below. In my opinion and based on your code there is no need to do elif.

```
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        reg = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if reg.is_valid():
            user = reg.save(commit=False)
            role = reg.cleaned_data.get('groups')
            group = user.set_add(user)
            reg.save()
            return redirect('register_user')

    else:
        reg = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'django_starter_app/register.html', {'register':reg})
```

Comment: the code did not work It gave me this error `Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead.`